# Is there a way to get the pointer that was access during the handling of a signal?

Tags: c++, windows, segmentation-fault, signals

Approximately the code is this:

```
#include <signal.h>

void SegmentationFaultHandler( int signal ) {
    if ( signal == SIGSEGV ) {
        // how to check here if it's actual null pointer?
        Throw( NullPointerException, "Object pointer not set to an instance of an object." );
    }
    else
        Throw( InvalidOperationException, "Signal has been intercepted by wrong function." );
}

int main( ) {
    signal( SIGSEGV, SegmentationFaultHandler );
    try {
        int *i = null;
        *i = 0;
...
```

How can I check if I didn't double check a pointer, or just accessed uninitialized data and deference it?

I know it's possible, because debuggers can know which address the program tried to access.

Comment: I don't think the debuggers work that way.

Comment: @Boiethios Debuggers work by overriding signals and then plant bad instructions to create breakpoints(?)

Comment: Maybe you can use `sigaction` instead?

Comment: @KarstenKoop I wish I were in Linux.

Comment: debuggers know that because they analyze the process memory (starting from the call stack and register contents at the time of the crash). If you want your software to be able to do so as well, you'll just about have to embed a debugger in it. In other words : why bother if you can just run a debugger ?

Comment: If you only need this for windows, you could use structured exception handlers. You would get an EXCEPTION_RECORD and CONTEXT structure with detailed information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you can retrieve PEXCEPTION_POINTERS inside your handler using _pxcptinfoptrs global variable which is declared inside signal.h. Then use this pointer as in below examples.

```
static void sigsegv_handler(int signo)
{
    PEXCEPTION_POINTERS excptr = _pxcptinfoptrs;
    if (excptr != NULL) {

    }
    // ...
}
```

**Vectored Exception Handler**

Under windows you can use [Vectored Exception Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/ms679274(v=vs.85).aspx). You handler will look as follows:

```
LONG WINAPI ExceptionFilter( struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS * pExceptionPointers ) {
```

then:

```
pExceptionPointers->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode
```

is you exception code, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION is when you access invalid memory.

```
pExceptionPointers->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation[0] == 0
```

is true when read operation was done

```
pExceptionPointers->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation[0] == 1
```

is for write operation

```
pExceptionPointers->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation[1]
```

is the address which was being read/written when exception happend

**Structured Exception filtering**

If you cannot use vectored exception handler then you may add __try/__except at the lowest level of your code, ie. in main() or where you thread function is being exectured:

```
 __try {
    // Code which might cause access violation or any other hardware exceptions
 } 
 __except(ExceptionFilter(GetExceptionInformation())) {
 }
```

Comment: I can't set up __try and __except, I have to make it throw the proper exception. Anyway I found a way to do like like the signal handler way. You can do it with `AddVectoredExceptionHandler( 0, ... )`.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky I have just updated answer, see at the top - but honestly I have never used _pxcptinfoptrs

Comment: Don't mind, I missed a single line. (The answer was OK from the start)